# Is that possible to use != in query string?

Tags: list-view, filter, query-string

I am filtering sharepoint list using query string for some reson i need to check condition like FieldValue!=Red is that possible to achive?

Or still its limitation?

Lists/Tasks/Task%20Summary.aspx?FilterName=EYHealthIndicator&FilterMultiValue=Red;Yellow&&FilterField2=ContentType&**FilterValue2!=Task**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no support for that in with standard SharePoint

The standard only specify that everything between '?' and '#' or end-of-url is the query string, but it's commonly aggreed that the format of the query string is 'ParamName=value[&ParamName=value]...', so the '=' in the querystring isn't specifying a condition it's only separating the parametername and the value

Comment: Do we have any other option to do this?. Also if i have two different content type is there any problem filtering the list?Task is filtering properly and i have one more contentype called taskfolder(Folder) its not filtering anyway...

Comment: You can only filter on equals, but you can limit your `Task Summary` view to only show `Task`s

Comment: In my view i have both task and Summarytask,But its not filtering Summarytask it filters only task. Even the filed i am using to filter is different and its common to both xummary task.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [dupe question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582066/is-that-possible-to-use-in-query-string/10596442)

> You can't AFAIK.
>
> The workaround MAY be to create a calculated column and then filter on
>   that.
>
> E.g. create a column called "Not-Red" with formula
>
> =IF([YOUR_COLUMN_NAME]="Red","False","True")
>
> Then filter
>
> ?FilterField1=Not-Red&FilterValue2=True

Answer (score 0):

try

Lists/Tasks/Task%20Summary.aspx?FilterName=EYHealthIndicator&FilterMultiValue=Red;Yellow&&FilterField2=ContentType&FilterValue2=Task&**FilterOp2=Neq**